# Projeto de conta bancaria aparece um bug. SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at getAccount at addAmount

Tags: node.js

````
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const chalk = require('chalk');

// modulos internos

const fs = require('fs');

operation();

function operation() {
    inquirer.prompt([{
        type: 'list',
        name: 'action',
        message:'O que voce deseja fazer?',
        choices: [
            'Criar conta',
            'Consultar saldo',
            'Depositar',
            'Sacar',
            'Sair'
        ],
    },
]).then(answer => {
    const action = answer['action']
    if(action === 'Criar conta') {
        createAccount();
    } else if (action === 'Consultar Saldo') {
    
    } else if (action === 'Depositar') {
        Deposit();
    } else if (action === 'Sacar') {

    } else if (action === 'Sair') {
        console.log(chalk.bgBlue.black('Obrigado por usar o Accounts!'))
        process.exit()

    }
}).catch(err => {console.log (err)})
}

//create an account

function createAccount () {
    console.log(chalk.bgGreen.black('Parabéns por escolher nosso banco!!'))
    console.log(chalk.green('Defina as opções da sua conta a seguir'))

    buildAccount();
}

function buildAccount() {

    inquirer.prompt ([{
        name:"accountName",
        message:'Digite um nome para sua conta!'

    }
]).then( answer => {
    const accountName = answer ['accountName']

    console.info(accountName)

    if(!fs.existsSync('accounts')) {
        fs.mkdirSync('accounts')
    }

    if (fs.existsSync(`accounts/${accountName}.json`)) {
        console.log(chalk.bgRed.white("Este nome já está em uso, por favor escolha outro nome!"))
        buildAccount()
        return
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(`accounts/${accountName}.json` , 
    '{"Balance} = 0',
    function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    },
    )
    console.log(chalk.green("Parabéns! Sua conta foi criada com sucesso "))
    operation();

}).catch((err) => {console.log (err)})
}

// Depositar montante na conta

function Deposit() {
    inquirer
        .prompt ([
        {
            name : 'accountName',
            message:'Qual nome da sua conta?'
        }
    ])
        .then((answer) => {
        const accountName = answer ['accountName']

        //verificando se a conta existe
        if(!checkAccount (accountName)) {
            return Deposit()
        }

        inquirer.prompt ([{
            name:'amount',
            message:'Quanto você deseja depositar?'
        },
    ]).then((answer) => {
        const amount = answer ['amount']

        // adicionar montante
        addAmount(accountName,amount)
        operation()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

}
function checkAccount (accountName) {
        if(!fs.existsSync(`accounts/${accountName}.json`)) {
        console.log(chalk.bgRed.black('Esta conta não existe, tente novamente!'))
        return false
    }
        return true
    }

function addAmount (accountName,amount) {

    const account = getAccount(accountName)

    console.log(account)

    }

function getAccount (accountName) {
    const accountJSON = fs.readFileSync(`accounts/${accountName}.json`, {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        flag: 'r'
    })

    return JSON.parse(accountJSON)
}```
````

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.